# Java - Scanner won't recognize double value from file

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor, double, java.util.scanner

I am trying to save values from a tab-separated file into a class. My problem is that my scanner will not recognize the last token as a double.

My file:

```
    Saint Lucia 179667  0.46
    Bosnia & Herzegovina    3503554 -0.10
    Tajikistan  9107211 2.08
```

The code that throws the error:

```
    while (fiSc.hasNextLine()) {
        temp.add(new Country(fiSc));
    }
```

Constructor for Country class:

```
    public Country(Scanner fiSc) {
        name = fiSc.next();
        pop = fiSc.nextInt();
        rate = fiSc.nextDouble();
    }
```

Temp is a LinkedList of the type Country where I am storing the file information. Country holds the name (String), population (int), and growth rate (double). I have tried constructing the Country class by first creating the object and adding the object after, however, I was able to pinpoint the problem to the last token.

When I try this code:

```
        while (fiSc.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(fiSc.next());
            System.out.println(fiSc.nextInt());
            System.out.println(fiSc.nextDouble());
        }
```

I get:

```
    Saint Lucia
    179667
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at MyMain.fillList(MyMain.java:61)
    at MyMain.main(MyMain.java:11)
```

Comment: What is your default locale (or the locale you set on the scanner)?

Comment: Just a blind guess: maybe your Scanner expects a locale specific decimal separator. For instance in Germany you would write `0,46` instead of `0.46`. Maybe you give it a try?

Comment: I did not set any locale on the scanner, just used the default one. I am from the US so I would assume that it should read, in @UniversE's example,     0.46 and not     0,46.

Comment: Oh oh, I think I see what is going on here. I tested your example and found out, that it is irrelevant, if you want to read a double, or an integer. My guess is, that the last token contains the line separator and thus it cannot be converted to any kind of number. Try to read the file line by line with a `BufferedReader` and then process the lines  with your `Scanner`. That should work.

Comment: I did set the delimiter to include new line using:        `fiSc.useDelimiter("\\t|\\n+");` so I thought I had covered the line separator. I'll have to read about `BufferedReader`, I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not in your code but in your input file.
Your input file looks like that every new line begins with a tab character and ends with a Newline character (invisible). The problem here is that the next character after your last (double) value is not a tab but a line break (Newline).
Simply said, the `Scanner` tries to extract the values between each delimiter - in your case between tabs. But when the `Scanner` tries to read the last value in the line, the result value for the last value in the first line (e.g.) would be look something like this: `0.46EOL`*, this is obviously not a double value and result in a `InputMismatchException`.

The easiest solution to fix the problem would be to remove the leading tabs of each line and append after every last value of a line a tab too.
For example, the first line should look like this: `Saint Lucia` `TAB` `179667` `TAB` `0.46` `TAB` (replace `TAB` with an actual tab).

* `EOL` Newline or 'end of line' character. More Information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: I looked at the format/whitespace characters of the file and the file is formatted: `Saint Lucia TAB 179667 TAB 0.46` like you had (except for the ending tab. The file instead shows the carriage return character (a squarish symbol) and  ❡. In the comments above, I noted I changed the scanner delimiter using: `fiSc.useDelimiter("\\t|\\n+");` so I thought I covered the new line.

Comment: @JoshBrown I see what you want to try, but this is outside of the question scope... but if you really want to do it like this, then I would change your statement as follows: `fiSc.useDelimiter("[\r\n]|\t");` (on Windows). The problem here is that the new line character is still in the cache of the `Scanner`, you need to skip that. For your example, after `rate = fiSc.nextDouble();` you need to skip the new line character with `if(s.hasNext()) s.skip("[\r\n]");`.

Comment: I've been away so I just now tested the code and it worked except I needed to add a plus sign to the skip method. It works as `fiSc.skip("[\r\n]+");` Thanks for the help